# Replace string with DOM element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string in which I like to replace some part with DOM element:

```
var mainStr = 'akedf abc dde';

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.id = 'word';
span.innerHTML = '123';
$(span).click(this.touchHandler);

var n = mainStr.replace('abc',span.innerHTML);

var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
htmlObject.innerHTML = n;


touchHandler:function(e){
    console.log('log something')
},
```

this code does not work, the 'abc' string is replaced with '123' but the touchHandler does not work.

The code is in Backbone.js

Is there some way that I can do this?

Comment: Might help if you include the code for `touchHandler` if it's the bit that's not working.

Comment: you attach the click event to `span`, yet you only use `span.innerHTML`, this can't clone the event, so just attach the event to `$('span',htmlObject)` instead, and use `outerHTML`, not `innerHTML`

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery, so why bother with `document.createElement()` when jQuery lets you do the same thing with less typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not like this. The way you insert the span into the document (`var n = ...`) treats the span as dumb HTML and leaves it to the browser to actually create the element and insert it into the DOM; your own `span` element is not inserted, therefore the click handler doesn't work.

You can attach the handler to the actual element this way:

```
var mainStr = 'akedf abc dde';

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.id = 'word';
span.innerHTML = '123';

var n = mainStr.replace('abc',span.innerHTML);

var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
htmlObject.innerHTML = n; // the browser creates new span element
$(htmlObject).find("span").click(this.touchHandler); // click handler attached
```

Comment: Thanks this worked with one change var n = mainStr.replace('abc',span.outerHTML); as user2786485 suggested.

Answer (score 2):

1. you are attaching the event to a different element, that doesn't exist in `htmlObject`.
   you need to attach the event to the `span` element that is within `htmlObject`, because `innerHTML` doesn't copy event listeners
2. when you use `innerHTML` you dont actually get `"<span>123</span>"`, instead you get `"123"`.
   you can either use `span.outerHTML` or just a string `var spanString = "<span>123</span>";` and `var n = mainStr.replace('abc',spanString);`

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4QRp/)